# Adding NuGet server from Azure App Service(NuGet.Server) with AD Authentication results 401 unauthorized in VS2019 proffesional

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have created a nuget server project.

[nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server)

and published it as an Azure App Service. So far, everything has worked fine. I added the server to Visual Studio and pushed some libraries to the server.

The NuGet.Server Azure App Service and the NuGet-server Package source in Visual Studio require a single-tenant login.

I have created a Microsoft identity provider to enable App Service Authentication with a redirect to Microsoft, which returns HTTP 302 Found for unauthorized requests. This works fine for the App Service.

In Visual Studio Professional, after adding the package source **https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/nuget**

I get a login prompt for login credentials where i have inserted my company's Microsoft account details.

which results in the following error:

> [AzureNugetServer] The V2 feed at
> 'https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/nuget/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net5.0'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
> returned an unexpected status code '401 Unauthorized'.

Is it possible to use Microsoft single tenant to connect the NuGet server in Visual Studio, did I do something wrong here?

Is there another option without adding usernames and passwords to the web.config file?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

- Try Closing VS2019
- Go to windows management credentials and remove all those that where related with your packages
- Reopen VS2019 and restore the Nuget Packages for your solution. It asks for your credentials, set it up.
  **Or**
- Close Visual Studio, then remove any credentials relating to the Azure DevOps server (e.g., `[domain]`, `VSCredentials_[domain]`) in Credential Manager.
  Then reopen Visual Studio, open NuGet Package Manager again and this time (on the 'Installed' tab) enter  credentials including the domain (domain/username)